# Change background color of material dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I read a couple of questions here but I can't make the background color of a dialog to change. Here an example using the - as I thought would be the correct way - panelClass property.
I manage to change the outline, but not the background color.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jm9gob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `outline` property works but the `background-color` one doesn't is because the `test` class is actually being applied to the container the dialog renders in rather than the dialog itself so the `background-color` may very well be working on THAT element but you can't see it because the dialog covers it while the outline exists outside of the dialog which is why its visible.

Normally if we have a stylesheet to go along with our component we can style the root element with the `:host` selector like this

```
:host{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

seeing that you're not using a stylesheet with your component I just wrapped your code in a `<section>` tag like this

```
<section class="dialogContainer">

  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

added the background to the `<section>` element in your `styles.scss` like this

```
.dialogContainer{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

now the background works.

[Here's a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jm9gob-q4g95z?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) to the working demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the right element using the `test` class. The following style will work:

```scss
.test {
  .mat-mdc-dialog-surface.mdc-dialog__surface {
    outline: 2px solid purple;
    background: black;
  }
}
```